# Google Apps Scripts. Exception "Недействительный аргумент"

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Может кто сталкивался? Не могу определить истинную проблему.
Есть код в скрипте файла гугл ТАБЛИЦЫ:

```
function addNewRowIfNeedIt(activeSheet) {
  try{
    var maxRow = activeSheet.getMaxRows()
    var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow()

    if (lastRow +5 >= maxRow){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRow, lastRow+5-maxRow)
      return true
    }
    return false

  }catch(error){Logger.log(error) } 
}
```

Он проверяет, есть ли в конце пустые 5 строчек в заданном листе - если нет - добавляет, чтобы были. Запускается из других функций, которые что-то заполняют в строчке.

Так вот, когда другие юзеры (кроме меня, создателя скрипта) запускают скрипт, который в свою очередь вызывает эту функцию, выскакивает ошибка "Недействительный аргумент" в строке:

```
activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRow, lastRow+5-maxRow)
```

хотя при этом сама операция выполняется! 
Пример функции для Юзера:

```
function fillRowOtpravka(){
  try{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

    // Если необходимо - добавляется новая строчка
    addNewRowIfNeedIt(sheet) 
    // Дата операции
    sheet.getRange("B" + rowI).setValue(new Date())
  }catch(error){Logger.log(error)}
}
```

Прошу Вас ткните меня носом, куда рыть?

Comment: Не могу повторить проблему. Попробуйте просто создать новый проект и скопировать туда текущий код. Очень похоже на какой-то баг. Например, сейчас зависают строки при программной обрезке. Удаление есть, а отобращение прежнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (lastRow +5 >= maxRow){
  activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRow, lastRow+5-maxRow)
  return true
}
```

Вот здесь крылась ошибка... Дьявол скрывался в мелочах.... вместо >= должно быть только >

Допустим, последняя заполненная строчка = 10
Максимум строк = 15

Тогда условие пройдено было (10+5 >= 15)
И скрипт пытался сделать вот это:
insertRowsAfter(15, 10+5-15) = insertRowsAfter(15, 0)

Второй аргумент в виде нуля и давал эту ошибку...